# How to implement peer discovery using Kademlia (rust-libp2p)

Tags: rust, p2p, kademlia, libp2p

I saw bunch of "answers" across the internet, but couldn't find any reliable example.

Here is the step by step process I would like to implement:

- Start node A
- Start node B by bootstraping Kademlia with node A
- node A and B start exchanging messages, or heartbeats (trough gossipsub for example)

I got two issues with this:

-> The first is that despite connecting B to A (A emit `RoutingUpdated`, A doesn't seems to discover B (it doesn't emit an event).
So through gossipsub, B send heartbeat to A, but not the other way around.
When facing this issue, both nodes are running on the same local machine (but I use public addresses).

-> The second issue arise when I try to connect two nodes from different machine, either on the same network or not. When doing so, I cannot manage to connect two nodes together.
The address A is exposing is responding to the `ping` command, but the `telnet` command timeout. I took down all my firewalls, VPN and everything that could block the request, but nothing changed. Also, as both node were working on WSL, I looked into windows ip configuration and tried every IP I've found, but couldn't get past this issue.

Once both issues are solved, I will make a small repo that expose a reliable example, because that's what I couldn't find online, and I think it would benefit the community.